# Notepad++ - Remove lines containing duplicate URL in a dynamic class

Tags: url, duplicates, notepad++, lines

this is a pretty specific question regarding Notepad++, or any other way you think I can separate these, frankly. I'll give you a quick example:

```
<div class="image" style="position: absolute; left: 260px; top: 0px;"><img src="http://www.Imagelink1.com/1"></div>
<div class="image" style="position: absolute; left: 520px; top: 0px;"><img src="http://www.Imagelink1.com/1"></div>
<div class="image" style="position: absolute; left: 180px; top: 0px;"><img src="http://www.Imagelink1.com/1"></div>
<div class="image" style="position: absolute; left: 210px; top: 0px;"><img src="http://www.Imagelink1.com/1"></div>
```

Despite their styling and positions, how would I delete all of these lines while maintaining the first of the duplicate lines (due to the ImageLink URLs being the same). It would be easy to just 'Search and Replace', if it weren't for the positions and some of them having the same link.

It's much more complicated than that, but how would you go about deleting this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the URL is the part that should be unique?
My way to do that would be to seperate the url's from the rest of the HTML, for example by using a regex and replacing everything that's not the URL, or by using block-select in Notepad++ and select all the URL's.

Then I'd paste the URL's in one column in Excel and paste the complete line (including the HTML) in the second column.
Then simply filter the first column by uniqueness:

- Select the first column containing the URL's
- Click the data-tab
- There's a button "Remove duplicates". Click that.
- It will ask if you want to expand the selection or use the selected column only. Tell Excel to expand the selection (because we want to filter all columns)
- Then a window will popup asking which column contains the duplicate values. Select only column A because that's the column containing the URL's.
- If you then click OK (or whatever the button is named) it will remove the duplicates like it should.

Then copy the second column back to Notepad++ and you'd have the unique lines.

Comment: I apologize for being ignorant, but do you think you can expand on the Excel filtering? I've gotten to the point where I need to filter by uniqueness, however, I'm not sure where to go from here. Do I select both columns, or only the first? Then do I simply just press the 'Advanced' button next to Filter, and check 'Unique Records Only'? I did so, and it seemed to not do anything. I'm sure my setup may be off a bit. But thank you for the answer!

Comment: Yes indeed that is the filter you should use. You should use that on the first column only (so on the URL that is).

Comment: I'm starting to doubt: maybe I'm wrong and you can only filter by a whole row. One moment, I'll try it myself

Comment: Sure thing. I'm filtering it like you said, and it's not doing anything to my right column. Is my HTML column (right one), supposed to have all the original HTML, including the links in which are in the left column? Perhaps that's why. Edit: Here's a screenshot. Not sure if it'll help or anything. http://puu.sh/czvRj/e091938652.png

Comment: You're a legend, brother. Thank you very much! Saved me several hours and future headaches. Marked your answer.